# Underscore in Doi in bibtex file

Tags: bibtex, urls, doi, underscore

In my bibtex, there are url links for DOIs with underscores which are causing compilation errors.

Here is the bibtex:

```
@inproceedings{LVR19,
    author = {Author},
    title = {Title},
    doi = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-25543-5_1}
}
```

And here is my error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.72 ...tps://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-25543-5_1}
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

My solutions that haven't worked:

1. changing the doi from a url to just the number
2. inclulding \url{} and \usepackage{url}
3. Changing the '_' to '\ _'

Does anyone have any other ideas I could try?

Edit: Bib set up

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
content here

\bibliography{bibfile}
\bibliographystyle{splnce04}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about trying to use `\ ` just before the `_` so that it reads `foo\_bar`?

Comment: How the `doi` field is handled and typeset will depend on the bibliography style you use (and possibly on additional packages you load in the preamble). It would help us enormously if you could add a full example document to your question where you show us your bibliography setup.

Comment: Most bibliography styles I know would probably prefer `doi = {10.1007/978-3-030-25543-5_1}` over `doi = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-25543-5_1}` but the exact implementation is up to the style. Most styles that I know at least have the possibility to use the `url`/`hyperref` package. In that case it would be counter-productive to escape `_` as `\_` (even though it may work).

Comment: @moewe and @oliversm , I did try using ```\_``` and it didn't work. I updated the example to try to make it more understandable. My apologies, I am still new with stackexchange.

Comment: Is `splnce04` a typo for `splncs04`? If not, where can we get hold of that file? (I downloaded the class from https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `llncs` class defines a very rudimentary `\doi` command that cannot deal with special characters.

We can define our own slightly more robust version of `\doi` by going back to  `url`'s `\url` command. Since `llncs` defines its `\doi` in `\AtBeginDocument` we have to do that as well. The proposed solution requires `\usepackage{url}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}` (it will work fine with either package).

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\doi#1{\url{https://doi.org/#1}}}
\makeatother

%\urlstyle{same}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{LVR19,
  author = {Author},
  title  = {Title},
  doi    = {10.1007/978-3-030-25543-5_1},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
content here \cite{LVR19}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{splncs04}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1. Author: Title. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-25543-5_1]

Comment: this gives me an error of `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@makeother #1->\catcode `#1
12\relax
l.72 ...ps://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-25543-5_1}}`

Comment: @AndyH The minimal working example I posted in the answer produces no such error. Please try and reproduce the error in minimal working example you can share.

Comment: Also make sure your `doi` field contains only the `doi` and not a `\url` or `\doi` command. To be sure delete your `.bbl` and `.aux` files before you recompile with LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX.

Comment: Deleting the `.bbl` and the `.aux` and recompiling worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that worked for me with `llncs` and underscore characters in DOIs is:

```latex
    \usepackage{underscore}
```

in the preamble. See https://ctan.org/pkg/underscore.

Comment: Thank you for this nice solution after a lot of searching.